Which type of Partition to choose for MicroSD Card (Sandisk)
I have a 1TB SD Card and thought of changing the corrupted SD Card with a different file system. There are many options categorized into groups like Generic, Linux, Windows, and Other and I wanna know which partition type to choose from.


Depends on purpose. Since you didn't tell us anything about we can't give you any advice.

exFAT is the only sensible format if you want cross OS support.
If all you use is Linux and want Windows users to need to go through a bit more work: ext3 or ext4.
